# imported python module of functions does not recognise package imports

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have files in a repo with the following Structure:

**RepoName\main.py**

**RepoName\functions\myfunction.py**

Inside `myfunction.py` is:

```
import pandas as pd
def make_ticker_list():
    constituents = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
    
    ticker_list = ""
    for x in constituents:
        ticker_list = ticker_list + x + " "
    del x
    return ticker_list
```

and inside `main.py` is:

```
import pandas as pd
from functions.myfunction import *

new_list = make_ticker_list()
```

but when I run `main.py`, I get:

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

I've imported the pandas alias already in main.py so I don't know why I get this error. I added it to myfunction.py as shown above, but that also didn't work

**Tried so far and didn't work:**

1. Adding import pandas as pd into the myfunction.py file, as shown above
2. Adding a '`__init__.py`' into the functions folder

The logic makes sense because when I load another toy function into myfunction.py, eg:

```
def toy()
    return 2
```

And I run `toy()` in `main.py`, it works fine

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: I could run this without error `python main.py`. In which python environment are you trying to run this?

Comment: I've tried it on VSCode and Spyder with no luck. I got the same error message with both

Comment: Do you get output if you add `print(f'{id(pd)}')` after the imports in `main.py`?